# Android Cardview foreground rim not visible

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have the following CardView with a custom foreground rim `android:foreground="@drawable/cardview_rim"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_82sdp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/cardview_rim"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_1sdp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
            android:padding="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"


            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Name"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="@string/Status_Semicolon"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_StatusProperty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_Status"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_3sdp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_3sdp"

            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_Status"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_Status"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Ordered"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Status"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="@string/Ordered_Semicolon"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Ordered_Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_Ordered"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_Ordered"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_Ordered"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_52sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_52sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
             />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_recyclerViewIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/recyclerViewIcon"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recyclerViewIcon"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/recyclerViewIcon"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/recyclerViewIcon"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the XML code for the `@drawable/cardview_rim`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
</shape>
```

Unfortunately the black foreground rim is not visible. Do you know why?

**Reminder**: Does anybody have a suggestion as to why I am not seeing the rim that I created? I'll appreciate every suggestion.

Comment: Is the rim a vertical bar shaped object in visual?

Comment: @Kozmotronik: What do you mean by "vertical bar shaped object in visual". It is actually a rectangel with a black rim. I had already posted the XML code of the rim in my question. There you can see how it looks (just copy and paste it to a XML layout file in Android Studio).

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to figure out the shape, get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```xml
app:cardForegroundColor="@drawable/cardview_rim"
```

instead of

```xml
android:foreground="@drawable/cardview_rim"
```

### Update

You can create the same effect by using the `stroke` property of the card view. Get rid of the foreground atrribute Then add the following attributes:

```xml
app:strokeColor="#000"
app:strokeWidth="5dp"
```

### Update 2

I think I found your issue. The `cardUseCompatPadding` attribute somehow prevents the drawing of the foreground. So use the same card configuration as in your question but this time just set the `cardUseCompatPadding` to **false** or delete it from the xml.

```xml
app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
```

##### Result in xml preview

[image: Result showing image]

Comment: Thanks Kozmotronik for your answer. Unfortunately it did not change anything and the rim is still not visible.

Comment: Can you try the same settings with a plain color like a plain black?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kozmotronik. I tried your suggested code with `app:strokeColor="#000"` and `app:strokeWidth="5dp"` but it did not change anything. Further, I tried `app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorGrey"` but this unforunately also did not make the rim visible.

Comment: Umm, those attributes do not apply for [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView) but they do for [MaterialCardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView). Do you mind to use material card view instead which is a subclass of card view, or you want to keep using the cardview?

Comment: I want to keep using cardview

Comment: @VanessaF Check for **Update 2**

Comment: Tried Update 2. No change at all.

Comment: Interesting, I've modified your own xml file take a look the result in my answer. By the way, You don't see the rim in run time or you don't see the rim in xml design at all?

Comment: Now all of a sudden it works. I just restarted Android Studio. But you are right that I need the attribute to be `app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"`. I accepted and upvoted your answer. Thanks for your help Kozmo.

Comment: You're welcome. Then it was an xml rendering issue of Android studio. Well, no harm done, eventually you got it working as you wish.